# Web Scrape for URL in Div Python (BeatifulSoup)

Tags: python, html, css, typeerror

Here's the div:

```
<div class="theoplayer-poster" style="z-index: 1; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%; background-size: contain; cursor: pointer; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; background-image: url(&quot;//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180424173851-ten-0425-00011501-exlarge-169.jpg&quot;);"></div>
```

I'm tring the get the `url(&quot;//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180424173851-ten-0425-00011501-exlarge-169.jpg&quot;)` into a string.

This is what I tried:

```
def cnn_get_thumb(cnn_url):
page = urlopen(cnn_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
img = soup.find('div', class_="theoplayer-poster")['style':'url']
img = title.text.strip()
return img
```

However, this results in a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you post the url you are tyring to scrape?

Comment: https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/24/cnn10/ten-content-weds/index.html
There it is. I'm just using it as a learning example so that I can expand later.

Comment: if you print `soup` you can see that there is no element with class `theoplayer-poster`

Comment: That's strange, it's in the html... Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's added dynamically after the page load.

Comment: There is a javascript part above the video player, perhaps the video is dynamically loaded using javascript. Are you sure JS is parsed completely before you scrape?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is. How can I be sure?

Comment: @Spiralio I checked it, and indeed the video is loaded through a script. You will probably need a full parser for this like Selenium.

Comment: What Ian posted did the trick. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @Spiralio A way to check this yourself is disabling Javascript and checking if your element is still on the page. It is not.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your main problem is the URL you specified doesn't contain a div class of that name. The following code works with the contents of the URL, hopefully it explains enough to figure out how to parse out what you want.

FYI, a quick print of soup will give you all the text, send that to clipboard, put in editor that can highlight text and search for the url you're after. Navigate back to see div class etc.

Also re JS parsing above - urlopen is not going to parse the JS for you - only a browser object is going to do that. If your string requires JS parsing to insert it into the dom I suspect you're out of luck.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# example div
# <div class="js-gigya-sharebar gigya-sharebar" data-description="April 25, 2018" data-image-src="//cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/180424173851-ten-0425-00011501-super-tease.jpg" data-isshorturl="true" data-link="https://cnn.it/2HVJmx0" data-subtitle="" data-title="CNN 10 - April 25, 2018" data-twitter-account="CNN"></div>


def cnn_get_thumb(cnn_url):
    page = urlopen(cnn_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    img = soup.find('div', class_="js-gigya-sharebar")['data-image-src']
    return img


print cnn_get_thumb("http://cnn.com/2018/04/24/cnn10/ten-content-weds/index.html")
```